# No module Sklearn but is installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As title says i get error that module cant be found but i installed it I searched 2 days but still cant find solution that 
I have 64 bit win 10, and python 3.4 
EDIT: After fixing typo i am getting error below and i am  searching and trying all solutions non is working for me please help

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

Comment: Post the logs here.

Answer (score 2):

You've mis-spelt `sklearn` as `sklern`.